# interpolation of variables in appears not to apply to psql --command. Should this be expected?

Tags: psql

Is it to be expected that `psql` does not perform variable interpolation on strings supplied as value of `--command`/`-c` option?

Specifically, I was surprised to find that this is an error:

```
$psql -v x=1 -c 'select :x'
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: select :x
```

whereas the following is not:

```
$ psql -v x=1 <<<'select :x'
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Obviously I have a "workaround" using my (bash) shell's "Here String" capability.

I'm just wondering if there is a "good reason"(tm) for this discrepancy.

Comment: "Why" questions are typically hard to answer and opinion based.

Comment: The reason is probably that either nobody noticed it or cared about it enough to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I was seeking an opinion, specifically as to whether this behavior should be expected.  My opinion is that it should.
Fair enough @a_horse_with_no_name - so now I've noticed it and reported it to postgres mailing list with id #17453.  If I get a a better informed response, I'll follow up here as well.